# Right button that calls actionsheet in toolbar

Tags: ios, xcode

As per subject of my question I've got my actionsheet function being called from navigation bar fine, however I have one view that has simple toolbar on it. I would like to reuse my actionsheet function and have the button on it as well. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: To elaborate further, I have following code that works fine for NavigationBar, however I would like to add exactly the same function but on toolbar? 
<code>
   UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(didPressShare)];    
    shareButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;</code>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand what you are asking but to call an actionsheet on a toolbar it's like this:

```
 [actionSheet showFromToolBar:self.toolBarController.toolbar];
```